# How do I get a variable to be passed across into the next Step, in AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a very simple step function.

**Start -> Lambda Function -> DynamoDB PutItem -> End**

**The Lambda Function Exports This:**

```json
{ 
  "statusCode": 200,
  "responseTime": 0.5
}
```

This data is sent to **DynamoDB:PutItem**

API Parameters of DynamoDB:PutItem

```json
{
    "TableName": "MyTable",
    "Item": {
        "statusCode": {
          "S": "$.statusCode"
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is with **$.statusCode** this is wrong as it just inputs the actual string **"$.statusCode"** instead of its value.

How do I pass across the **statusCode** from my Lambda function to this next step?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

```
{
    "TableName": "MyTable",
    "Item": {
        "statusCode": {
          "S.$": "$.statusCode"
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add a .$ after the key